# Cannot conect to my aws postgress database in RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created my Postgres database in AWS but it has connection timeouts every time I try to connect (using JDBC or pgadmin). I even added security groups but that didn't help.
[image: Text]
[image: Text]
Since I'm new in AWS I really have no idea what to do. Should I check any logs or I missed something during set-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to check:

- Database was launched with `Publicly Available = Yes` (Done!)
- Security Group permits inbound access from your IP address or `0.0.0.0/0` (Done!)
- DNS Name resolves to a public IP address (I checked, it does!)
- Database was launched in **public subnets** (Defined as having a Route Table entry pointing to an Internet Gateway)
- Your network permits the traffic (can test on different networks, eg Home vs Office vs Tethered via your phone)

I tried connecting from my computer and it timed-out too, and I know that my "network permits" such traffic.

Therefore, it seems likely that the database was launched with a subnet group that contained only **private subnets**, which are not reachable from the Internet.

**Update:**

It appears that the database has been launched with a Subnet Group that contains private subnets rather than public subnets.

If you have not yet connected to the database / stored any data, it would be easiest to:

- **Delete** the current Amazon RDS instance
- Create a **Subnet Group** that contains public subnets
- **Launch** a new Amazon RDS instance using the new Subnet Group

For security, you should adjust the Security Group to only allow access from your IP address (removing the entries for `0.0.0.0/0`).

Comment: should I create a new subnet or to customize existing?

Comment: Have you investigated the current subnets to confirm whether they are public or private subnets?

Comment: They are private. I created a public Elastic IP and associated it with my subnet. And now it says: ' FATAL: database "chatdb" does not exist'

Comment: An Elastic IP address is not required. The DNS Name provided will resolve to a public IP address.

Comment: The 'FATAL' error you mentioned suggests that you _are_ now connecting to the database server without a timeout? The 'database name' would be `postgres` by default, unless you specified a different one during launch (see the Configuration page). This is _different_ to the db-identifier, which is `chatdb`. Otherwise, I suggest that you create a new subnet group and a new RDS instance. I have updated my answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

From where are you trying to connect?
If you’re trying from a local machine, the DB must be deployed in a public subnet, and must have a public IP.

Comment: from my laptop and pc.
can I add a public subnet?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that if you originally created the database in a subnet group that only had private subnets, there's a good chance that the network interface associated with the RDS instance will be attached to one of those private subnets and public access will not be possible (even if you've configured everything else correctly).

I've found that if I change the DB instance size it will force the network interface to be recreated and when it is recreated the network interface for the new DB instance SHOULD be attached to a public subnet which will help make the DB publicly accessible.